# How can I not show the undefined values from map() return

Tags: javascript

I have an import from a json file with a random text and I have to get all the words in which the first letters are vowels.

```
let texts = MyData.map(text => {
return text.tags.map(word => {
return word.split(' ').map( char => {
   if(char[0].match(/[aeiou]/i)) {
    return char
   }
})
});
});
console.log(texts); [ example : 'ea',       'in',
  undefined,  'in',
  'occaecat', undefined,
  undefined ]
```

So how can I make the return value be without the undefined values and in the same map function?

Sample data of MyData for anyone wondering :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "62bab08c83586a7bb36b46de",
    "index": 0,
    "tags": [
      "ea in minim in occaecat pariatur cillum",
      "ut exercitation minim officia enim cillum anim",
      "ad occaecat labore velit cupidatat enim proident",
      "consequat culpa qui occaecat sit sunt voluptate",
      "eiusmod excepteur adipisicing tempor ut Lorem do",
      "quis velit aliquip ad excepteur deserunt do",
      "dolor fugiat ea sit adipisicing labore in"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "62bab08c10365bb88f81cdf5",
    "index": 1,
    "tags": [
      "non laborum cillum commodo velit culpa commodo",
      "nisi aute magna laborum ut cillum velit",
      "in veniam ullamco officia aute deserunt ex",
      "dolor ullamco aliqua laborum ullamco officia mollit",
      "fugiat aliquip nostrud deserunt fugiat veniam veniam",
      "culpa eu irure ullamco ea deserunt ullamco",
      "labore quis quis enim magna duis cupidatat"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "62bab08cf0d1796087e71a27",
    "index": 2,
    "tags": [
      "esse labore aliqua sit voluptate mollit deserunt",
      "sint nulla minim veniam do nulla duis",
      "culpa enim laborum do magna voluptate amet",
      "commodo elit ad magna veniam proident duis",
      "aliquip ex dolore officia laboris sit qui",
      "esse anim velit ut quis do magna",
      "do culpa eu sint occaecat voluptate cillum"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "62bab08cbb8247421f46d095",
    "index": 3,
    "tags": [
      "ea aliqua cupidatat aute ipsum qui officia",
      "enim ad pariatur ex tempor pariatur irure",
      "in mollit aute sit occaecat non cupidatat",
      "adipisicing sint non elit nisi commodo sunt",
      "tempor veniam culpa exercitation in cillum pariatur",
      "non quis dolor in ea ut duis",
      "excepteur Lorem dolor qui tempor dolore reprehenderit"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "62bab08c642b523e6cc9ecd1",
    "index": 4,
    "tags": [
      "cillum nulla ipsum pariatur nisi ex in",
      "proident tempor aliquip id commodo sunt ut",
      "tempor qui ex laborum anim nisi excepteur",
      "consequat ea laborum cillum mollit enim consectetur",
      "nisi ut sint sunt non veniam ullamco",
      "proident exercitation culpa dolor duis enim qui",
      "commodo aliquip ipsum velit elit in nulla"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "62bab08c5702bc78e0e082db",
    "index": 5,
    "tags": [
      "deserunt sit labore veniam eiusmod tempor eu",
      "ut dolore est pariatur eiusmod cillum eu",
      "ex commodo voluptate Lorem incididunt dolor veniam",
      "labore ullamco quis et qui fugiat pariatur",
      "in duis ut tempor velit excepteur ut",
      "aute esse velit nisi et reprehenderit ea",
      "consectetur do aute et dolor ex do"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you share the sample data of ```myData```?

Comment: @Harry I think that [ examle : ..... ] represents the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use <kbd>[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)</kbd> in inner most map function

```
let texts = MyData.map(text => {
    return text.tags.map(word => {
        return word.split(' ').filter( char => {
           if(char[0].match(/[aeiou]/i)) {
            return char
           }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Undefined starts with 'u', will it still pass the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap` twice, once to flatten out all the items to their `tags`, and then again to flatten all the tags to a set of words. Then it's just a `filter`

```
const result = example.flatMap(x => x.tags)
                      .flatMap(x => x.split(" "))
                      .filter(x => x[0].match(/[aeiou]/i))
```

Working code below with your input.

```js
const example=[{"_id":"62bab08c83586a7bb36b46de",index:0,tags:["ea in minim in occaecat pariatur cillum","ut exercitation minim officia enim cillum anim","ad occaecat labore velit cupidatat enim proident","consequat culpa qui occaecat sit sunt voluptate","eiusmod excepteur adipisicing tempor ut Lorem do","quis velit aliquip ad excepteur deserunt do","dolor fugiat ea sit adipisicing labore in"]},{"_id":"62bab08c10365bb88f81cdf5",index:1,tags:["non laborum cillum commodo velit culpa commodo","nisi aute magna laborum ut cillum velit","in veniam ullamco officia aute deserunt ex","dolor ullamco aliqua laborum ullamco officia mollit","fugiat aliquip nostrud deserunt fugiat veniam veniam","culpa eu irure ullamco ea deserunt ullamco","labore quis quis enim magna duis cupidatat"]},{"_id":"62bab08cf0d1796087e71a27",index:2,tags:["esse labore aliqua sit voluptate mollit deserunt","sint nulla minim veniam do nulla duis","culpa enim laborum do magna voluptate amet","commodo elit ad magna veniam proident duis","aliquip ex dolore officia laboris sit qui","esse anim velit ut quis do magna","do culpa eu sint occaecat voluptate cillum"]},{"_id":"62bab08cbb8247421f46d095",index:3,tags:["ea aliqua cupidatat aute ipsum qui officia","enim ad pariatur ex tempor pariatur irure","in mollit aute sit occaecat non cupidatat","adipisicing sint non elit nisi commodo sunt","tempor veniam culpa exercitation in cillum pariatur","non quis dolor in ea ut duis","excepteur Lorem dolor qui tempor dolore reprehenderit"]},{"_id":"62bab08c642b523e6cc9ecd1",index:4,tags:["cillum nulla ipsum pariatur nisi ex in","proident tempor aliquip id commodo sunt ut","tempor qui ex laborum anim nisi excepteur","consequat ea laborum cillum mollit enim consectetur","nisi ut sint sunt non veniam ullamco","proident exercitation culpa dolor duis enim qui","commodo aliquip ipsum velit elit in nulla"]},{"_id":"62bab08c5702bc78e0e082db",index:5,tags:["deserunt sit labore veniam eiusmod tempor eu","ut dolore est pariatur eiusmod cillum eu","ex commodo voluptate Lorem incididunt dolor veniam","labore ullamco quis et qui fugiat pariatur","in duis ut tempor velit excepteur ut","aute esse velit nisi et reprehenderit ea","consectetur do aute et dolor ex do"]}]

const result = example.flatMap(x => x.tags)
                      .flatMap(x => x.split(" "))
                      .filter(x => x[0].match(/[aeiou]/i));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the ones that are undefined after using map, or you could do this with reduce

```
    return word.split(' ').map( char => {
       if(char[0].match(/[aeiou]/i)) {
        return char
       }
    }).filter(char => char !== undefined)
```

or

```
return word.split(' ').reduce((acc, char) => {
    if(char[0].match(/[aeiou]/i)) {
        return acc.concat(char)
    }
    return acc
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let texts = MyData.map(text => {
return text.tags.map(word => {
    return word.split(' ').filter( char => {
       if(char[0].match(/[aeiou]/i)) {
        return char
       }
    })
});
```

});